# spring JDBC bean property maaping with oracle object attribute

Tags: spring-jdbc, oracle-type

I have trouble to mapping oracle object attribute with its equivalent sprig bean property.

**Example:**

```
create or replace type typ_test is object(attr1 number,attr2 varchar(20));

Spring bean:
class Person{
private Integer sno;
private String sname;
//Getters and Setters
}
```

Now I want to map the oracle object type attribute with Spring bean object (Person).